# swift splitViewController programmatically show master view

Tags: ios, swift

I have project with splitViewController as on image (iPhone version). [image]

On masterVC I have tableVC, on detailVC I have some information about items from masterVC.
On detail VC I have a button. After touching this button I need go back to master view. If I do something like:

```
_ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

It has no affect. How to go back on masterVC?

Comment: What exactly do you want to archiev "go back to master view"?

Comment: @shallowThought I updated this info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `popToRootViewController:` in the detail viewcontroller will call it on the detailvc's navigation controller.

On the iPhone (assuming there's no split screen), if you want to dismiss the detail controller and go back to the master, you can do this

```
detailVC.navigationController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: may be you know hot to detect click back button?